# Cloud SQL Postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, port, google-cloud-sql, pgadmin

I can't connect to instance of cloud sql via pgAdmin. It says connection timed out. I know this could be due to the port 5432 not opened on the firewall, but in the Cloud SQL instance there's no firewall tab to open ports. Is there a way to open it?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview#external-connection-methods

Answer (score 2):

Auth proxy might be a good option. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-auth-proxy
It establishes the connection to the instance and opens up the local port through which applications can operate on the database.

Comment: The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is the best solution. Removes the need to whitelist IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[The doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-overview#external-connection-methods) offers a few options to connect, but as [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835703/5298879), the most locked-down are preferable. Out of those, if things get desperate and you already have:

- a Compute VM in the same network and [IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) in place, [`gcloud compute ssh --tunnel-through-iap`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) with [port forwarding on your ssh client](https://sysnews.ma.ic.ac.uk/ssh/port-forwarding-for-Windows-using-PuTTY.html) or [`--ssh-flag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag) to bounce off it and access the db
- another reachable Cloud SQL instance, there's [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) and [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) supported [extensions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#miscellaneous-extensions) you can use to cross-link

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, thank you guys. The problem was that I didn't register my PC IP in the network section. For this time that's okay, I will get the auth proxy when I send it to production.